# Is it safe to download DLLs?

Tags: security, virus, dll

From the title, the question you may assume I'm asking is "Can DLLs be malicious?" But I'm really asking if the mere act of downloading a malicious DLL can pose a threat to the security of one's computer. I know that DLLs contain executable code, but I'm under the impression that this code is only run per the request of an EXE file. So if that's true, then does a threat involving a DLL only occur when used as part of a larger executable program?

Comment: The mere act of downloading (nearly) anything is harmless it must be executed to be harmful.  Most malicious files mascurade as something else though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The threat of a DLL would be if gets executed by an executable. But if you download a malicious DLL, there are several ways it can get executed at the request of a non-malicious executable. You don't want a malicious DLL sitting on your machine.

For example, you probably have several executables on your machine right now that will happily load and execute any DLL requested by a variety of requests. The `regsvr32` executable is one of the most obvious.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff919712%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)'s an analysis of one other way this can happen. There are still more.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading of whatever is safe itself, and that's true not only for `DLL` but even for executable files (`.exe` and others), but running them is not safe.